# php prevent csrf attacks in mutiple submit

Tags: php, forms

I work with this PHP [class](https://github.com/BKcore/NoCSRF) for prevent CSRF from attack.

CODE:

```
$token = NoCSRF::generate( 'csrf_token' );

<form name="csrf_form" action="#" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>">
    ...Other form inputs...
    <input type="submit" value="Send form">
</form>
```

for check csrf:

```
try
{
    // Run CSRF check, on POST data, in exception mode, with a validity of 10 minutes, in one-time mode.
    NoCSRF::check( 'csrf_token', $_POST, true, 60*10, false );
    // form parsing, DB inserts, etc.
}
catch ( Exception $e )
{
    // CSRF attack detected
}
```

this worked for me when i have one from in my page But when i have two form in my page only work with one form and in other form submit always show `CSRF attack detected`.

php check FORM 1:

```
if($_POST['submit'] == "from") && !empty($_POST['username'])){

   try
      {
        // Run CSRF check, on POST data, in exception mode, with a validity of 10 minutes, in one-time mode.
        NoCSRF::check( 'csrf_token', $_POST, true, 60*10, false );
        // form parsing, DB inserts, etc.
    }
    catch ( Exception $e )
    {
        // CSRF attack detected
    }
}
```

php check FORM 2:

```
if($_POST['submit'] == "from2") && !empty($_POST['username'])){

   try
      {
        // Run CSRF check, on POST data, in exception mode, with a validity of 10 minutes, in one-time mode.
        NoCSRF::check( 'csrf_token', $_POST, true, 60*10, false );
        // form parsing, DB inserts, etc.
    }
    catch ( Exception $e )
    {
        // CSRF attack detected
    }
}
```

HTML FORM:

```
 <form name="csrf_form" action="#" method="post">
             <?PHP $token = NoCSRF::generate( 'csrf_token' );?>
            <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>">
            <input type="text" name="username">
            <input type="submit" value="form">
        </form>
    <form name="csrf_form" action="#" method="post">
             <?PHP $token = NoCSRF::generate( 'csrf_token' );?>
            <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>">
            <input type="text" name="badname">
            <input type="submit" value="form2">
    </form>
```

how do fix this OR how do work this class for multiple form?!

class source [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BKcore/NoCSRF/master/nocsrf.php)

Comment: Why do you check isset($_POST['from2']), there is no such an input with name from2 in your html code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20587746/one-token-vs-multiple-tokens-to-prevent-csrf-attacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are only calling `NoCSRF::generate()` once. If it's called more than once, data for the old token will be overwritten, making it invalid.

Alternatively, use a different key for the two tokens (instead of using `"csrf_token"` for both).

Comment: you right. this is a safe if i generate for all form/post one csrf token?